# Require.js best practise when loading different scripts depending on local conditions

Tags: requirejs

For the sake of argument, say I want to load Zepto by default, but use jQuery instead for IE (all versions).

What would be a sensible way to do this when using Require.js?

Comment: how are you expecting to do browser detection?

Comment: in the above example, probably, ('\_\_proto\_\_' in {})

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches: "proper" but long and "sleight of hand" but short.

"Proper" but long:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery:'path/to/jquery'
        , zepto: 'path/to/zepto'
    }
})

var iNeed = []

if (!('__proto__' in {})) {
    // This is IE
    iNeed.push('jquery')
} else {
    // Everything else
    iNeed.push('zepto')
}

require(iNeed, callback)
```

"Sleight of hand" but short:

```
var AMDConfig = {
    paths: {
        jquery:'path/to/zepto'
    }
}

if (!('__proto__' in {})) {
    // This is IE
    AMDConfig.paths.jquery = 'path/to/jquery'
}

require.config(AMDConfig)

require(['jquery'], callback)
```

The reason the "sleight of hand" is not "proper" is that you are masking the real nature of what stands behind "jquery" As you grow your app, some jQuery plugins may come and not work over zepto, but it will not be immediately clear what the issue is.

The "proper" solution is also a problem in one respect - if you define the requirements array dynamically, the build tool like `r.js` will not be able to find other dependencies you put there.

Your pick..